# Retrieve JSON from URL by sending 2 variables from my android app in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

im trying to post 2 variables (1 int, 1 string) from my android app on a url and get back JSON response. Actually im doing the same on a website and i want to do it also in my android app.

Code on website:

```
    $.ajax({'
    type: "POST",
    url: "my url", //my url
    data: JSON.stringify({"number": number,"day":"MONDAY"}), //number is an integer and day is a string variable
    contentType: "application/json;",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
    }
    error: function (jxhr) {
        //do some thing
    },
    complete: function (msg) {
       var text = msg.responseText 
       var obj = JSON.parse(text);
    }
```

Can anyone please help me to do the same thing in java for android using android volley or any other way?

Thank you!

Comment: An all in one solution is the Volley Library -- tutorial here -- very easy to use after some setup -- http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: With retrofit2 is really easy. You need to try with that library.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement a singleton  stringrequest or json request. Use HashMap to put your parameters.

```
StringRequest postReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urlPost, new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
                // do your thing
                String text = response;
                }}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // error response
        }){
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams()
    {Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    // the POST parameters:
    params.put('number', number);
    params.put('day', 'MONDAY');
    return params;}
};
Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext()).add(postReq);
```